# Pass String from one Activity to another activity, android

Tags: java, android

Here is my code below for passing string from one intent to another:

**Activity1**

```
Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.captionText);
        String s = et.getText().toString();

        System.out.println("***caa" + s);  
        //text is printed here which i type in editText of my app.

        Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class)
        i.putExtra("Caption",s);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
});
```

**Activity2**

```
Bundle b = getIntent.getExtras();
String str = b.getExtraString("Caption");
System.out.println("***A2 ",str); // here i m getting null
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
tv.setText(str); 
// and therefore here text is not able to set in textView.
```

Have also tried using

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 i.getStringExtra("Caption");    // Still no result
```

Have searched a lot on StackOverflow and tried most of the possible solutions but still not getting.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity 1 :
 In you onCreate()

```
     EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.captionText);
```

in your onClick()

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String personStr = et.getText().toString();

   if(personStr != null && !personStr.trim().equals("")) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
   intent.putExtra("PERSON_KEY", personStr);
   startActivity(intent);
   }
```

In your activity 2 onCreate():

```
   String personStr = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PERSON_KEY");
   // do nullcheck after getting from bundle..
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass the string without onCreate() method...... I hav this code in onActivityResult() method

Comment: if you have onActivityResult in activity1 and activity1 code to activity2. it is possible....

Comment: instead of startactivity, you have to use setResult(..) and finish() in activity2

Comment: I my oncreate() method ,there is an intent to start the camera, thats it. In my onAcvtivityResult() method i hav previewCapturedImage() method so from this   i want to pass my captionText to another activity. In previewCapturedImage() there is image preview and edit text for caption .

Comment: So thatz what i am doing, but not getting any result

Comment: camera intent is builtin intent which captures only camera parameters not user defined params... for that you can use preferences...

Comment: Confusing ...!!! Camera intent is fine ... My concer is about the string passing... Just like in whatsapp we do capture....preview and add caption and onclick of send ...image with caption appears ...similarly i want to do.

Comment: after capturing, you will load one screen to get caption right..? while pressing button write activity1 code there and don't call startActivity. ok... follow my second comment...

Comment: After capturing i m loading one screen to get CAPTURED IMAGE as preview and below tat edit text for adding caption....so in onclick of the send button only i m adding the code to pass string .

Comment: yes right. then previous activity you have to override onActivityResult() there use my activity2 code there for recieving this caption text.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work using the below code.

**Activity1**

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("Caption",s);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

**Activity2**

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String str = b.getString("Caption");
Log.i("string",str);
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass the string without onCreate() method...... I hav this code in onActivityResult() method

Comment: @RiteshKarmare the scenario is not clear.Edit the question to add more details.